# Interaction between a pencil and rubber (eraser)

Tags: everyday-chemistry, intermolecular-forces, adsorption

Is there a interaction between a graphite pencil and and a eraser. For example, if I drew a line on a piece of paper and then erased that, what interaction is occurring?

Is it a Van der Waals interaction with intermolecular forces or is something else?

Comment: @Mockingbird, agreed. My first thought is that the Van der Waals interactions between the graphite and eraser are just stronger than those between the graphite and the paper, but I hope someone has a more thorough answer than that ;) Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I also share the same thought..

Comment: It's called friction which is mechanical and not "chemical". Does the rubber erase the graphite if you just put it on your scribbles and don't rub it? I find that most chemists forget about the simple world of mechanics all too fast.  Apply a thin layer of something on a surface and then rub it -> it vanishes. Must be hydrogen bonding, right? Wrong. Call it Pauli repulsion if you want

Comment: Tribologists will tell you that friction and wear are complex phenomena with mechanical, physical, and chemical components. The answer is complex.

Comment: @JonCuster : If the initial poster and the commenters try to argue with Van-der-Waals interactions, I think saying friction/Pauli repulsion is sufficient. If you look at anything in detail, things get very complicated ...

Comment: @AMT , there are several types of non-abrasive erasers that essentially do work by a wiping action or even just "blotting" the graphite from the paper. After reading about this a bit I can't decide if I should try to answer it or flag it as too broad! It's more interesting than appears at first glance.

Comment: @AMT, how do you think friction works? Afterall, is it not theoretically impossible for two bodies of matter to come in to direct contact?

Comment: @Bob Maybe it depends on your definition of van der Waals forces. I really do not like this term because it isn't well defined. There are different definitions, some so broad that basically everything becomes van der Waals interaction. I think the key thing is that even the mentioned "non-abrasive erasers" seem to work (I'm not an expert in erasers) with at least a little bit of pressure. I think this makes saying Van der Waals interaction misleading. Yes, friction has something to do with dispersion as well, but that is not the full story. I don't see how "friction" isn't the right answer

Comment: @airhuff It certainly is. I would like to read that answer even if the initial poster hasn't been seen since. If you have a really good one, please share it. If you want to look at it in great detail, we might get a very interesting picture. You got charges, surface irregularities (do perfectly even surfaces still erase?), adsorption to some degree I guess and a thousand different things. I wonder how much research has been done with erasers though.

Comment: I asked for a school project, however since the various different opinions I might have to make an argument report, stating different opinions. I've been looking and researching into this, but it's difficult to find anything relevant. However I thank you all for these arguments!

Comment: Please don't, there are no two opinions. Maybe you misunderstood. The debate was about what forces cause friction, not if friction was the thing to look for. This really shouldn't be a chemistry assignment. I would also be surprised if there was a debate about what causes friction, it's just not something your average chemist can answer on a quantum mechanical level.  Also please read this, even though it's one of the worse articles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Friction_at_the_atomic_level

Answer (score 2):

There was much discussion in the comments to the OP regarding whether erasing a pencil mark is a chemical process or merely a mechanical process, akin to removing an oil spill with high pressure water (my analogy). But I think the answer to "Is it a Van der Waals interaction with intermolecular forces" is clearly yes.

Although the classic "pencil head" eraser generally requires a vigorous rubbing action to rapidly remove a pencil mark, even this can be done in a manner that shows pencil marks that had been bound to the paper via intermolecular forces are transferred to a material having a stronger affinity for the pencil mark than does the paper.

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eraser) Wikipedia article discusses several types of erasers that clearly illustrate a chemical process rather than a mechanical one is dominating the removal of the pencil mark. For example, regarding the "poster putty" type of eraser the article states:

> "...poster putty works much the same as traditional kneaded erasers,
>   but with a greater tack or lifting strength...Repeatedly touching the
>   putty to a drawing pulls ever more medium free..."

A "gum" eraser also clearly works by adsorbing graphite from paper. As the gum is dabbed or lightly rubbed on the pencil mark, the intermolecular forces holding the graphite to the paper are weaker than the intermolecular forces between the graphite and the erasure. The following photo from the above Wikipedia article shows that the graphite in the used eraser has accumulated over time. There is no evidence of paper or other material having accumulated along with the material from the pencil mark.

[image: gum erasers]

Furthermore, one can imagine using different materials that should make for good erasers if the pencil marks are simply being removed by the mechanical action of an eraser. For example, if that's the case, shouldn't you be able to remove the pencil mark by rubbing it off with a piece of wood, one's finger, another piece of paper, a fingernail, etc.?

Comment: You can erase the pencil marks with your finger. I'm not convinced by your arguments. One type of eraser absorbs graphite quite heavily, so all erasers function via "van der waals" interaction? I've mentioned in the comments that this by itself is an extremely vague term. So why do you need to rub your eraser then? The way I understand it, it is 1) rubbing the eraser thus loosening the graphite 2) some kind of absorption process by the material to prevent smearing, is this correct?